# org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager

Tags: myfaces, tomcat8

After a migration of an aplication with MyFaces 2.2.5 from tomcat7 to tomcat8

i have this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
       org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager cannot be cast to 
            org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager
    at org.apache.myfaces.spi.impl.Tomcat7AnnotationInjectionProvider.initManager(Tomcat7AnnotationInjectionProvider.java:183)
    at org.apache.myfaces.spi.impl.Tomcat7AnnotationInjectionProvider.postConstruct(Tomcat7AnnotationInjectionProvider.java:85)
```

I check the DefaultInstanceManager class of tomcat8 its effectively implements the interface org.apache.tomcat.InstanceManager, so its probably a security class loader issue

Any idea how to fix that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Context>
.....

    <Loader delegate="true" /> 

</Context>
```